# HTML string from API not being converted to HTML rendered entities

Tags: php, html

I'm receiving a chunk of HTML via API call and trying to put that HTML into my template for it to render. But, instead of rendering, it's being printed out as if it were a string.

**Example of HTML string from API:**

`\u0026lt;p\u0026gt;\u0026lt;strong\u0026gt;Hello World\u0026lt;/strong\u0026gt;\u0026lt;/p\u0026gt;`

**Then in the controller I convert the string to HTML entities**

`$content = htmlspecialchars_decode($response['content']);`

**The issue I'm having is that in my view, the HTML is printed (tags and all) instead of being rendered as HTML:**

In view code:

`<?= $content ?>`

End result:

`<p><strong>Hello World</strong></p>`

How can I get this HTML chunk to render in my view?

Comment: is it possible tat your page doesn't have text/html content-type?

Comment: I don't think so. I have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` in the <head>

Comment: show all your code, including how you are calling your view.

Comment: `\u0026lt;` is `&lt;` unicode encoded so all you're getting with `htmlspecialchars_decode` is `&lt;` - which means if you view source you'll still see things like `&lt;p&gt;` rather than `<p>` ... which is why you're seeing printed code... I think. Try `utf8_decode` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data looks like double-encoded. Try

```
$content = htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($response['content']));
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of your string, you don't need `htmlspecialchars_decode()`, since you don't have HTML special characters directly in it.

I suspect you are getting your data in JSON format. A JSON-encoded value can sometimes have special characters converted to Unicode constants (for example, the PHP `json_encode()` function does that when used with the [`JSON_HEX_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php#constant.json-hex-tag) options).

Try this:

```
$content = json_decode('"' . $response['content'] . '"');
```

Comment: It does have HTML special chars in `\u0026lt;` = `&lt;` (unicode encoded) = `<` (html encoded)

Comment: In that sense, yes. What I meant is the string doesn't have special HTML entities directly in it, so `htmlspecialchars_decode` won't do anything at all.

Comment: Ah yeah, gotcha - that's why I suggested `utf8_decode()` first, that should flip `\u0026` to `&` which would give `&lt;` which *should* then be flipped by `htmlspecialchars_decode()` to `<` ;)

Comment: The point is, I don't think `utf8_decode` would do that. It would try and change the character encoding of the string to ISO-8859-1, but you would still have something like `\u0026lt;` in a different character encoding. I'll try to clarify the answer.